# Qt наличие символа в шрифте

Tags: c++, qt, шрифты

Как в C++ Qt определить, есть ли определённый символ в выбранном шрифте?

В идеале нужна функция, я ей даю char в котором содержится символ и название шрифта в виде QString или QFont,а на выходе получаю true, если шрифт может отобразить этот символ, иначе false.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение:
юникод номер символа 查 равен [26597](https://unicode-table.com/ru/search/?q=26597), пробуем проверить есть ли этот символ в Times New Roman

```
QRawFont rawFnt;
rawFnt=rawFnt.fromFont(QFont("Times New Roman"));
QChar ch=QString("查").at(0);
bool b1=rawFnt.supportsCharacter(ch);//проверяем по символу
bool b2=rawFnt.supportsCharacter(26597);//проверяем по коду
qDebug()<<b1<<b2;//выведет  false false
```